# Linkedin: 2nd degree connections checking

Tags: linkedin-api

We have a list of about 400 people who are prospective biz dev targets that we are cultivating.

We're looking for a way to see who on that list I'm 2nd degree connects with (and also who the mutual connections are). It can be done manually for each 1 of the 400, but this takes a long time. Also when I add a new contact, I'd like to see if they are linked to any of the 400.

Perhaps, it's possible with the API or some such?